# dataGridView displays 2016-09-01 instead of 2016-09-01 00:00

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview

I have a problem. DataGridView displays only date if time is midnight. First I thought that is because of my LINQ query which is dataGridView's data source. I couldn't change the query so I decided to add zeros from code. This is my code:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewRaporty.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridViewRaporty.Columns.GetColumnCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible); j++)
                {
                    string wartoscKomorki = dataGridViewRaporty.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                    if (wartoscKomorki.Contains("-") && wartoscKomorki.Length == 10){
                        wartoscKomorki = wartoscKomorki + " 00:00";
                        dataGridViewRaporty.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = wartoscKomorki.ToString(); 
                    }
                }
            }
```

I was surprised because zeros weren't added. Then I displayed those values in MessageBoxes and zeros appeared there. The conclusion is that dataGridView has got those values with zeros but doesn't show them. Is there any solution to show full DateTime format?

Comment: So your if clause fails? Use the debugger! Also: Your ToString without format string takes no control; why?

Comment: It doesn't matter because dataGridView already has got this value with zeros just doesn't show them.

Comment: To control what is shown use a format string!

Comment: Format string doesn't work.I already told you that dataGridView has got this value with zeros so formatting it again doesn't change anything.DataGridView has got this value but displays it without zeros!Convert.ToDateTime(wartoscKomorki).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")

Comment: Well, I wonder why you keep loading strings into the Cell value, but that is up to you. What value type does the column have? Of course formatting will only work with DateTime and you do not need to add a ToString to a string valriable..  Maybe your cell is too small? Btw: you do not need to spaculate about the content of a cell, you can look at it in the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said all was because of dataGridView behaviour. This is the solution:

```
dataGridViewRaporty.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.Format= "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
```